# Macro increment

Tags: macros, sas

I have table lookup values as below

```
sno date
1   200101 
2   200102
3   200103
4   200104
```

I wrote below macro

```
%let date=200102
 proc sql;
 select sno into :no from lookup where date=&date.;
 quit;
```

I need a help on how to convert the entire table lookup into macro increment by creating first s.no and date as two macro variable then increment. So that i don’t need to update dates in my table lookup every time. So if i look up for date 201304 i need to get its corresponding s.no

Comment: What you posted is not a macro, just some SAS code.  Note that your `%let` statement that is defining a the macro variable DATE is missing the semicolon to end it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there pattern to the SNO values?  Are you basically numbering the months since 01JAN2001?  If so then use `INTCK()` function.

```
data test;
  input date yymmdd8. ;
  format date yymmdd10. ;
  sno = 1+intck('month','01JAN2001'd,date);
cards;
20010112
20010213
20010314
20010415
;
```

So you could create two macro **variables**. One with the base date and the other with the base SNO value.

```
36   %let basedate='01JAN2001'd ;
37   %let basesno=1;
38   %let date='01JAN2001'd ;
39   %let sno=%eval(&basesno + %sysfunc(intck(month,&basedate,&date)));
40   %put &=date &=sno;
DATE='01JAN2001'd SNO=1
41
42   %let date="%sysfunc(today(),date9)"d;
43   %let sno=%eval(&basesno + %sysfunc(intck(month,&basedate,&date)));
44   %put &=date &=sno;
DATE="16NOV2017"d SNO=203
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it did work... I need one more help how to put all these sno into separate dataset

Comment: Not sure what you mean about a separate dataset. Do you have data with dates that you want to calculate SNO values for? If so then use the `INTCK()` function directly in the data step. No need for macro logic complexity when working with data. Perhaps you can start a new question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Build a lookup table dynamically and create a macro variable for each row in the table.  The macro variables will be named `date_200101`,`date_200102`,...and so on.  They will contain a value equal to the corresponding `sno` value:

```
data lookup;
  length var_name $20;
  do sno = 1 to intck('month','01jan2001'd,date())+1;
    date = input(put(intnx('month','01jan2001'd, sno-1, 'beginning'),yymmn6.),best.);
    var_name = cats('date_',date);
    call symput(var_name, cats(sno));
    output;
  end;
run;
```

You can then refer to the macro variables like so:

```
%let date =200103;
%put &&date_&date;
```

...or...

```
%put &date_200101;
```

The first usage example is using double macro resolution.  Basically the macro processes needs to perform 2 iterations of the macro token `&&date_&date` in order to fully resolve it.  On the first pass, it gets resolved to `&date_200101`.  On the second pass, the macro token `&date_200101` gets resolved to `1`.

Comment: I dont want to have lookup table. I want to create macro with initial value say i will start my sno as 111 and date as 200101 then do increment...so that ii can delete the lookup table and use only macros

Comment: @suresh You can delete the lookup table after the `call symput` step and it will still work.  The lookup table is just to simplify the creation of the macros.

Comment: Oh I see, you don't want to have to edit the lookup table at all.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply translate one (unique) value into another. You can use (in)formats. They can do much more than just changing how data are read/displayed. They are easy to use, fast (in-memory) and don't depend on the table once created. Change the library to a permanent one if work (=> temporary library) doesn't suit your needs.

```
options fmtsearch=(formats,work);

data fmt(keep = fmtname type start end label hlo default);
length fmtname $10 type $1 start end $6 label 8 hlo $1 default 8;
fmtname = 'date_to_no';
type = 'I';
label=0;
do y = 2001 to 2099;
    do m = 1 to 12;
        start = put(y,4.) || put(m,z2.);
        end = start;
        label + 1; 
        default=50; /*default length of the string compared when informat is used. Should be higher than both start and end*/
        output;
    end;
end;
/*if you want to assign a value (=label) to inputs not found. In this case it's -2*/
hlo="O";
start = "";
end = start;
label= -2;
output;
run;

proc format library=work cntlin=fmt;
run;

data test;
no = input('200101',date_to_no.); output;
no = input('201710',date_to_no.); output;
no = input('201713',date_to_no.); output;
run;
```